# Joomla admin redirects to language code after login

Tags: login, redirect, joomla-3.9

I've been extensively searching the web but found no useful solution and would be happy for any input.

After migrating the site to a new server (Apache, no apparent changes, just newer) and adding the (cPanel Auto) SSL, the admin (mydomain.com/administrator) displays a login page but after clicking on "Login", I get constantly redirected to mydomain.com/de/administrator (or whatever language [code] is selected on front-end) and I get

> 404 error: Category not found

¯\_(ツ)_/¯ (go figure).

I've already:

- tried to change sef and sef_rewrite settings in configuration.php,
- double checked the cookie_domain and live_site,
- cleared the cache,
- tried a different browser, but was unable to login to the admin.

Can you help me to find a solution to be able to login? Is there any other way to disable automatic language override plugin or something?

Comment: You are welcome to retract your question if you like because this is not likely to be beneficial to future developers.

Comment: Alternatively, you can post an answer to your question and state the resolution.  I suppose there could be an off chance that someone else will encounter the same issue and will be able to resolve the issue in the same way.

Comment: Either way, @Gašper please decide on a system-recognized resolution.  Leaving a comment to say that you self-solved your issue will make this page _look_ unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my case: I had to change my admin password in the phpMyAdmin (DB) - don't know why, though, because I naver changed it before/after migrating the Joomla! to a new server - makes no sense but it works now.